# Nginx: verify if nginx if pulling from cache

Tags: nginx

I use nginx caching to cache html and assets. How can I verify if nginx is actually caching the assets and delivering from the cache?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add a header like so:

```
add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status
```

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUpstreamModule#.24upstream_cache_status

Comment: this header never shows up for me hit or miss